# Setting compileSdkVersion in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

To set build target in Eclipse we go to project `properties -> Android` and check the desired build target checkbox.  In my case Google APIs, 21.

To do the same in Android Studio it looks like I have to edit `build.gradle` and manually type a string into the `compileSdkVersion` entry that says "Google Inc.:Google APIs:21".  That seems pretty error prone and a step backwards.  What am I missing?

Found a post saying that I can instead hit <kbd>F4</kbd> and get the Project Structure dialog box where there is a dropdown for Compile Sdk Version but it only has "API 21: Android 5.0(Lollipop)" - no google api choice listed.  Even if I select that and save and clean, the `build.gradle` does not change from the prior entry (api 19).  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I am using AS 1.0.2

Comment: Just for clarification, what version of Android Studio & Channel do you have?

Comment: "What am I missing?" -- you're missing the fact that compiling against the Google APIs was usually unnecessary starting in 2008 and is even less common today. Unless you are using Maps V1, you do not even *want* to be compiling against that. And, if you are using Maps V1, please drop what you're doing and move to Maps V2, before Google turns off the old Maps V1 access.

Comment: I'm using AS 1.0.2 built on December 18, 2014

Comment: CommonsWare: I did not know that, thanks.  (still wondering how to change the setting)